# R writing summary of selected columns in a dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

with data like below,

```
text = "
a,b,c
NA,20,-10
1,10,5
2,5,-30
3,30,40
4,40,NA
NA,39,-24.9
"
df = read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T)
```

I can get `summary` values of specific columns as follows

```
summary(df[, c("a", "c")])
```

What I want is the summary results in a new dataframe with the column names in original `df` as row names and the summary attributes ( like `Min.`, `Mean` etc. ) as columns names like below

```
+---+--------+-------+
|   |  Min   | Mean  |
+---+--------+-------+
| a |   1.00 |  2.50 |
| c | -30.00 | -3.98 |
+---+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` and `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` you can do

```
library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame.matrix(summary(df[, c("a", "c")])) %>% 
     rename_all(trimws) %>%
     splitstackshape::cSplit(c("a", "c"), sep = ":") %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = names(.), names_to = c( "key", ".value"),
                  names_sep = "_") %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = `1`, values_from = `2`)

# A tibble: 2 x 8
#   key    Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max. `NA's`
#  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a         1      1.75    2.5  2.5       3.25     4      2
#2 c       -30    -24.9   -10   -3.98      5       40      1
```

---

Another approach could be to calculate `summary` for each column separately and then bind the results together.

```
cols <- c("a", "c")
map(df[cols], summary) %>%
  map(stack) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from =  ind, values_from = values)
```

You can `filter` the values which are not important to you.